# Continuously tailing a rotating log file with date and time in filename

Tags: bash, log-files, command, tail

I have a log file in format `log_name_YY-MM-DD_HH_mm.log`. The log rotates every couple of hours and the new log is created containing the date and time of it's creation. Sometimes I need to tail the live output of this log with the `tail -f` command. After the log is rotated  tail still points to old filename and must be manually restarted with the new filename.

Is there a way to automatically switch `tail -f` to use the new file? The `tail -F` option (`tail --follow=name --retry`) doesn't work in this case because the filename of the log changes.

Comment: What is rotating the log file?  Could you setup a symlink to always point at the most recent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a script to tail the most recent log file in the background and then check regularly for a new log file. If there is a new log file, kill the old process and start tailing the new file.

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATTERN='log_name_??-??-??_??_??.log'

CURRENT=any_pattern # dummy pattern to start off first tail -f

while true; do
   NEWLOG=`ls -t $PATTERN|head -n1`
   if [[ $NEWLOG != $CURRENT ]]
   then
      kill $TAILPID 2>/dev/null
      CURRENT=$NEWLOG
      tail -f $CURRENT &
      TAILPID=$!
   fi
   sleep 1 # check regularly
done
```

Comment: Thank you, I will probably use something like this. I will probably modify the script so that instead of killing the tail process it creates the simlink to new to the most recent log file. Then I can tail -F the simlink.